# What is the PDF of a function with 2 variables?

Tags: probability

The problem I'm working on involves finding the PDF of a function. In my case, my function is $$ f(r,\phi) = \frac{\cos{(2\phi)}}{r^2} \text{for   } b > r > a$$

The general recipe, as I've gathered, is to first find the inverse function. This yields the CDF. And then from there we take the derivative of the CDF to get to the PDF.

For the inverse, let's just consider the interval for $\phi$ to be $[0, \pi/2]$ since the $f$ is monotonic over that range and for $r$ let's do some arbitrary $[a,b]$ where both are positive numbers.

For a single value function, I understand how to get the inverse but for a multivariate function like this, I'm not quite sure where to begin. Should I do this piecewise?

Comment: your question doesn't make sense. there's no reason to "invert" at all. perhaps you mean integrate? 1) if you integrate f and then take the derivative, you're going to end back up at f. so, f is already your pdf (maybe you need a scaling constant?). 2) there's no domain listed for your function, but it's clearly not defined at r=0, so to find the scaling constant (if any) you'll need to calculate an integral based on some bounds you haven't given us.

Comment: true, this function exists for r>0. Finding the "PDF of a function" is the best way I can put it check out the classic textbook example here on finding the PDF of a sine wave http://atif-razzaq.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/probability-density-function-pdf-of.html

Comment: In, the example given in your link of $X=\sin(Y)$, $Y$ is a uniform random variable, so it makes sense to "find the PDF of $X$." If your question is supposed to be an analogue of this example, you need to specify that $r$ and $\phi$ are random variables...